# jQuery - Changing on click and on hover

Tags: jquery, html

I have 5 different img tags and for each tag there are four different states: **on**, **on-hover**, **off**, and **off-hover**. All of which have a corresponding src which I am changing with jQuery, so a total of 20 different png files. This all works fine, the problem comes when I have text next to each img tag that needs to change color according to what the img tag it is next to is changing. I also need the img tag to change if the text is either clicked on or hovered.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="sheilds">
    <img class="sheild_icon" id="icon1" src="../img/icon1-on.png"  />
    <img class="sheild_icon" id="icon2" src="../img/icon2-on.png" />
    <img class="sheild_icon" id="icon3" src="../img/oxicon-on.png" />
    <img class="sheild_icon" id="icon4" src="../img/icon4-on.png" />
    <img class="sheild_icon" id="icon5" src="../img/icon5-on.png" />
</div>

<div class="text_pannel">
    <div class="icon_text" id="text_icon1"><p>Outdoors</p></div>
    <div class="icon_text" id="text_icon2"><p>Groups</p></div>
    <div class="icon_text" id="text_icon3"><p>Icons</p></div>
    <div class="icon_text" id="text_icon4"><p>Sports</p></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript/JQuery Code:**

```
$(".sheild_icon")
    .mouseover(function() {
        this.src = this.src.replace('.png', '-hover.png');
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        this.src = this.src.replace('-hover.png', '.png');
    })
    .click(function() {
        if (this.src.indexOf('-on') > -1) this.src = this.src.replace(/(.*)-on(.*)/, "$1-off$2");
        else this.src = this.src.replace(/(.*)-off(.*)/, "$1-on$2");
    }
);
```

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ca2Kn/)

Comment: what is this half opening `<p>`tag here: `<p<p>Sports</p><`

Comment: Oh, that was a mistake while formatting the question. Thanks

Comment: You should really be using CSS with background-images for this. It's much cleaner an you don't need JS.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

adding and removing a different class to those text-elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ca2Kn/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".sheild_icon")
    .mouseover(function() {
        this.src = this.src.replace('.png', '-hover.png');
        $('#text_'+this.id).addClass('active');
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        this.src = this.src.replace('-hover.png', '.png');
        $('#text_'+this.id).removeClass('active');
    })
    .click(function() {
        if (this.src.indexOf('-on') > -1) {
            this.src = this.src.replace(/(.*)-on(.*)/, "$1-off$2");
            $('#text_'+this.id).addClass('active2');
        }
        else {
            this.src = this.src.replace(/(.*)-off(.*)/, "$1-on$2");
            $('#text_'+this.id).removeClass('active2');
        }
    }
);
</script>


<style type="text/css">
.active,
.active2 {
    color:red;
    font-size:20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: it works, except when trying to click on the text to change the state.

Comment: @Matt check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ca2Kn/2/ added the las few lines of javascript

Comment: the text works now, except if I click the text, I need the png to switch between on and off

Comment: @Matt I gave you an idea how you can try solve what ever you are looking for, never mind, but you can also try something yourself

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using CSS to do this.

```
<div class="icon_text" id="text_icon1"><p>Outdoors</p></div>
```

Becomes:

```
<div class="icon1"> Outdoors</div>
```

CSS:

```
.icon1 {
    background-image:url(/img/icon1-on.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
}

.icon1:hover {
    background-image:url(/img/icon1-hover.png);
}

.icon1.active {
    background-image:url(/img/icon1-off.png);
    color:#f00;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".sheild_icon").on('click', function() {$(this).addClass('active')});
```